# How to authenticate to Google BigQuery with the c# SDK?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm trying to [follow this Google example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-from-file) about Uploading a CSV file to Google BigQuery. Specifically, this code in the demo:

```
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
```

Now, I believe I have my `projectid` figured out, but I'm getting the following error:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

So I don't understand how I'm suppose to authenticate? What credentials do I use? Where do I get them from? Yes, I clicked the link in the error but I'm *still confused*.

For example, r[eading the docs about using the env var](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#GAC) `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, I just don't understand what it means. I need a json file .. but how do I get this? where does this go? Do I check this into my git repo?

Eventually, I hope to run my code in Azure Functions or the Google Cloud Functions.

Comment: Instead use env_var, maybe you can run Google Cloud CLI and authenticate with `gcloud auth application-default login` to generate the JSON file `application_default_credentials.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stating Google Documentation:

> Authentication is the process by which your identity is confirmed
> through the use of some kind of credential. Authentication is about
> proving that you are who you say you are.

Hence, to access Google's APIs and services we need proper authentication. You can use the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to provide the location of a credential JSON file. This JSON file can be one of the following types of files:

- credential configuration file for workload identity federation (More Information [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#GAC))
- service account key.
  For Service Account(SA) key, you can create a service account from IAM section, give the SA appropriate roles and generate json key, provide the path of this json key file to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.